# C# How to Use a service SAS to authorize a client object

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am creating a Blazor Webassembly app. I am using Azurite Storage Emulator to mimic Azure storage in development and I have installed Azure Storage Explorer.

I am following [Create a service SAS for a blob with .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/sas-service-create-dotnet) example to get my app to connect to my developer storage account.

In the example code that they provided:

```
// Create a Uri object with a service SAS appended
BlobClient blobClient = blobServiceClientSharedKey
    .GetBlobContainerClient("sample-container")
    .GetBlobClient("sample-blob.txt");
Uri blobSASURI = await CreateServiceSASBlob(blobClient);

// Create a blob client object representing 'sample-blob.txt' with SAS authorization
BlobClient blobClientSAS = new BlobClient(blobSASURI);
```

I'm not sure what the `blobServiceClientSharedKey` is.

I sort of know what a shared key is, but I don't know what they want me to do with it here. If I paste their code into visual studio, it doesn't compile. Visual Studio doesn't know what `blobServiceClientSharedKey` is.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

***Update: Solved***

Well, I got it working, but I don't think it is correctly utilizing the Stored Access Policy. But I wanted to post my code which allows me to create a blob without the container being set to allow anonymous access. I think it is at least somewhat secure.

```
public class StorageService
{
    private readonly IConfiguration configuration;

    public StorageService(IConfiguration Configuration)
    {
        configuration = Configuration;
    }
    public StorageSharedKeyCredential GetStorageSharedKeyCredential()
    {
        string? accountName = configuration["BlobStorage:Name"] ?? "";
        string? accountKey = configuration["BlobStorage:AccountKey"] ?? "";
        StorageSharedKeyCredential storageSharedKeyCredential =
            new(accountName, accountKey);

        return storageSharedKeyCredential;
    }

    public async Task<BlobContainerClient> CreateBlobClient()
    {
        // Create a BlobServiceClient object with the account SAS appended
        string? blobServiceURI = configuration["BlobStorage:Url"];
        string sasToken = await CreateAccountSAS(GetStorageSharedKeyCredential());
        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClientAccountSAS = new BlobServiceClient(new Uri($"{blobServiceURI}?{sasToken}"));

        BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient = blobServiceClientAccountSAS.GetBlobContainerClient(configuration["BlobStorage:ContainerName"]);

        blobContainerClient = await CreateStoredAccessPolicyAsync(blobContainerClient);
        return blobContainerClient;
    }


    public async Task<string> CreateAccountSAS(StorageSharedKeyCredential sharedKey)
    {
        // Create a SAS token that's valid for one day
        AccountSasBuilder sasBuilder = new AccountSasBuilder()
        {
            Services = AccountSasServices.All,
            ResourceTypes = AccountSasResourceTypes.All,
            ExpiresOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(1),
            Protocol = SasProtocol.HttpsAndHttp
        };

        sasBuilder.SetPermissions(AccountSasPermissions.All);

        // Use the key to get the SAS token
        string sasToken = sasBuilder.ToSasQueryParameters(sharedKey).ToString();

        return sasToken;
    }

    public async Task<BlobContainerClient> CreateStoredAccessPolicyAsync(BlobContainerClient containerClient)
    {
        // Create a stored access policy with read and write permissions, valid for one day
        List<BlobSignedIdentifier> signedIdentifiers = new List<BlobSignedIdentifier>
{
    new BlobSignedIdentifier
    {
        Id = "sample-read-write-policy",
        AccessPolicy = new BlobAccessPolicy
        {
            StartsOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
            ExpiresOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(1),
            Permissions = "rw"
        }
    },
    new BlobSignedIdentifier
    {
        Id = "sample-read-policy",
        AccessPolicy = new BlobAccessPolicy
        {
            StartsOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
            ExpiresOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(1),
            Permissions = "r"
        }
    }
};
        // Set the container's access policy
        await containerClient.SetAccessPolicyAsync(permissions: signedIdentifiers);

        return containerClient;
    }

    public async Task<string> UploadAsync(string base64, string userId)
    {
        var encodedImage = base64.Split(',')[1];
        var decodedImage = Convert.FromBase64String(encodedImage);

        try
        {
            BlobContainerClient container = await CreateBlobClient();

            if (await container.ExistsAsync() == false)
            {
                await container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
            }

            using (var fileStream = new MemoryStream(decodedImage))
            {
                BlobClient blobClient = container.GetBlobClient($"{userId}.png");                    

                // upload image stream to blob
                await blobClient.UploadAsync(fileStream, true);
                return $"{userId}.png";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

appsettings

```
"BlobStorage": {
    "ConnectionString": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "Url": "http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1",
    "ContainerName": "profile-pics",
    "Name": "devstoreaccount1",
    "AccountKey": "Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw=="
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even I'm not sure why official documentation mentions that. But, "blobServiceClientSharedKey" should be a "BlobServiceClient" object, which is injected in the constructor.

```
BlobClient blobClient = blobServiceClient
    .GetBlobContainerClient("sample-container")
    .GetBlobClient("sample-blob.txt");
Uri blobSASURI = await CreateServiceSASBlob(blobClient);

// Create a blob client object representing 'sample-blob.txt' with SAS authorization
BlobClient blobClientSAS = new BlobClient(blobSASURI);
```

[BlobServiceClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/blobserviceclient?view=azure-node-latest)

Make sure to add service in Program.cs file.

Comment: Ok, thank you. That makes sense, but not the way it is named. I will try that tomorrow and let you know. I did leave feedback on the documentation page to let them know that it was not a good example.